# Getting array object in forEach

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use IntersectionObserver property of javascript. And I've got a problem like below.
Basic specifications is like, when each `section` reaches to the top of browser (viewport), it's background color changes which from the color from colors array written in script.

**Problem:**
Each `section` area only gets the color of blue which is the last of colors array.

**Want to:**
When the top of each `section` intersects with top of viewport, each ones gets each color from colors array as it's background color.

**ex.** First section named green gets background color of green

Thanks in advance

```js
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section'); 
const colors = new Array('green','brown', 'blue');

colors.filter(color => {
  eachColor = color;
});

const action = function (entries, observer) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if(entry.isIntersecting) {
      entry.target.style.backgroundColor= eachColor;
      observer.unobserve(entry.target);
    } else {
      return;
    }
  });
}

const options = {
  root: null,
  rootMargin: '30% 0px', 
  threshold: 1 
};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(action, options); 

sections.forEach(section => {
  observer.observe(section); 
});
```

```css
header, footer { height: 200px; background: #ccc;}
.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: .5s;
}
.block1 {background: #666;}
.block2 { background: #aaa;}
.block3 { background: #333;}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<section class="block block1">green</section>
<section class="block block2">brown</section>
<section class="block block3">blue</section>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

Comment: _"you don't see these problems properly in this code snippet"_ - Then modify it so that it is a proper [mcve]

Comment: Have a look at how `Array.prototype.filter()` works

Comment: you must use not '=' in filter but '==='